# How do I keep Python Sockets secure for Multiplayer Games?

Tags: network, python, programming

I'm making a simple multiplayer game in Python. No personal/important data will be transferred between the server and client. I am using the Python sockets library to communicate between the client and the server.

However, I have done nothing special for security. I'm worried that someone could hijack the client-server connection of another player and control their actions in the game. Is this possible? Should this be a security concern, or are Python sockets safe from tampering?

Comment: How does the client identify itself to the server, such that the server can tell different clients apart? Does the player have to authenticate in any way, e.g. a password? Are you using TLS (HTTPS or otherwise) at all?

Comment: @CBHacking When the client joins a server, a connection object is created which I can use to communicate with the client.

Comment: In other words, you're just using the TCP session, which can be trivially spoofed by any man-in-the-middle, and you have no way to actually tell one player from another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a TCP connection, generally another player **wouldn't** be able to hijack the established client-server connection of another player.

**However**, someone controlling their network (the ISP of the player, the owner of the wifi it uses to connect, etc.) *would* be able to:

- view the contents of all packets transferred (including any authentication data)
- modify the commands sent
- replace their connection with its own
- MITM connections to the server

You could avoid this by doing your communication on top of TLS, instead of bare sockets.